# Como armazer valor de um ion-input em uma variável e passa-la na rota?

Tags: angular, ionic

Imagine o seguinte cenário no Ionic 4:
Tenho um ion-input para o usuário digitar o número de um Ticket. Quero armazenar esse valor em uma variável na classe do componente e depois utiliza-la para passar como parâmetro da rota.

Nesse contexto, não estou conseguindo armazenar o valor digitado no ion-input na variável, alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boa tarde,

Voce pode fazer assim o seu input dando um name com o mesmo nome do ngModel e cria sua variavel tipo assim 'public teste: string;'

````
<ion-input  name="teste" [(ngModel)]="teste" class="nome" type="text" ></ion-input>```
````

Comment: ótimo, eu sabia que era fácil, esqueci do tal "name" rsrs 
Obrigado! Agora meu Template ficou assim:

       <ion-input type="text" name="ticket" [(ngModel)]="ticket"></ion-input>